# Log4j2 Mule Issue

Tags: mule, log4j2

We have various mule applications deployed on our Mule 3.6.4 server all with their own log4j configuration defined in the classpath of the application as seen below. (example of 1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>

    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout
              pattern="&lt;%-4d{DATE}&gt; &lt;%-5p&gt; &lt;%t&gt; &lt;%m&gt; %n" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="file"
                 fileName="${sys:mule.home}/logs/apptest.log"
                 filePattern="${sys:mule.home}/logs/apptest.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">

      <PatternLayout
              pattern="&lt;%-4d{DATE}&gt; &lt;%-5p&gt; &lt;%t&gt; &lt;%m&gt; %n" />
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="console" />
      <AppenderRef ref="file" />
    </AsyncRoot>
  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

And these apps are deployed in this Order in Mule ESB

Application1
Application2
Appplication3

For some reason all the logging for the applications is outputting to the console and only the log file for Application 3. The logging isn't working for Application 1 or 2?

Anyone able to shed any light on this? Is this some classloader issue? We are running Mule 3.6.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Everything is going to console because you have `<AppenderRef ref="console" />` in your `<Logger>` config. You log4j config should be at the in each {app}/classes/.

For File appender, have you tried using different file name for each application -

```
<RollingFile name="file"
                 fileName="${sys:mule.home}/logs/app1test.log"
                 filePattern="${sys:mule.home}/logs/app1test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
```

For second app -

```
<RollingFile name="file"
                     fileName="${sys:mule.home}/logs/app2test.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:mule.home}/logs/app2test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
```

Comment: "You log4j config should be at the in each {app}/classes/." It is. We have a log4j2 for each application. The example you have given above is exactly what we are doing. We have three log4j files for each of the applications in their classpath

Comment: No nothing, all the logging from all three applications is outputting fine to the mule_ee.log and the 3rd applications log, which is the last application deployed. The application logging is broken for the first and second application. We can see logging for when it is deploying but none of the logger `<logger level="INFO"` definations are working

Comment: Blog http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/mule-3-6-asynchronous-logging/ here has configuration section that shows how log4j config is loaded, see if anything gives clue from there.

Comment: yes i've read this to no avail. everything is set up correctly according to the configuration.

Comment: Just came across this, https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/logging-in-mule#troubleshooting-logging. Try adding `-M-Dlog4j.debug=true` to verify which log4j files are being picked up.

Comment: i've tried this. I've added it to my startup script `./mule -M-Dmule.mmc.bind.port=$MULE_PORT -M-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -M-Dlog4j.debug=true` but it does not appear to be working

Comment: You don't see anything at the start on console? "This parameter writes the Log4j2 startup information, including the location of the configuration file being used, to stdout. You must remove that configuration file before your modified configuration can work."

Comment: I didnt see anything to do with log4j on start up no. I must remove what configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using append parameter for the RollingFile appenders? You could also consider giving a unique value for the RollingFile name for each app. Something like this:

For Application1 -

```
<RollingFile name="app2_file"
             fileName="${sys:mule.home}/logs/app1test.log"
             filePattern="${sys:mule.home}/logs/app1test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}" append="true">

  <PatternLayout
          pattern="&lt;%-4d{DATE}&gt; &lt;%-5p&gt; &lt;%t&gt; &lt;%m&gt; %n" />
  <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
</RollingFile>
```

For Application2 -

```
<RollingFile name="file"
             fileName="${sys:mule.home}/logs/appt2est.log"
             filePattern="${sys:mule.home}/logs/app2test.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}" append="true">

  <PatternLayout
          pattern="&lt;%-4d{DATE}&gt; &lt;%-5p&gt; &lt;%t&gt; &lt;%m&gt; %n" />
  <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
</RollingFile>
```

Comment: Yes I have a unique value for each app I have only posted an example of one application's logs. Each three have the same config but with a different log file name. I tried append="true" but no luck.